# Convert Fingerprint Image to Template with Java

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, iso

I am trying to convert a fingerprint image with format jpg to a template using the library
SourceAFIS
https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/

But I am receiving a few bytes that doesn't look like template (Minutiae data), any suggestions to achieve this goal?

```
   File[] images = directory.listFiles();
            File desiredfile = null;
            for (File file : images) {
                if (file.getName().equals("images.jpg")) {
                    desiredfile = file;
                    break;
                }
            }
     FingerprintTemplate template = null;
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            template = new FingerprintTemplate(
                                    new FingerprintImage(
                                            Files.readAllBytes(desiredfile.toPath()),
                                            new FingerprintImageOptions()
                                                    .dpi(500)));
                        }
                        fileLogger.log("template " + template.toByteArray());
```

**Conclusion**:
It seems the minutiae data is hidden and we can not see the actual bytes, the library aims to  use the template object for matching process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code should be like this.**

Make sure to replace "path/to/fingerprint/images.jpg" with the actual path to your fingerprint image. The code now includes error handling for file-related operations and logs the template size to the console.

```
public class FingerprintConverter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Replace "path/to/fingerprint/images.jpg" with the actual image file path
            String imagePath = "path/to/fingerprint/images.jpg";
            
            Path imagePath = Paths.get(imagePath);
            if (!Files.exists(imagePath) || !Files.isRegularFile(imagePath) || !Files.isReadable(imagePath)) {
                System.err.println("Invalid image file: " + imagePath);
                return;
            }
    
            try {
                byte[] imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(imagePath);
    
                // Step 3: Extract the fingerprint template
                FingerprintImage fingerprintImage = new FingerprintImage(
                        imageBytes,
                        new FingerprintImageOptions().dpi(500)
                );
    
                FingerprintTemplate template = new FingerprintTemplate(fingerprintImage);
    
                // Logging template information
                System.out.println("Template size: " + template.toByteArray().length + " bytes");
    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error reading image file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can't I log the actual bytes for template  (Minutiae data)  because the size is approximately 400 bytes. but I can only see few bytes like this [B@be703be. @Bhavik Nathani